# What exactly caused Data to get angry in "Descent" before the emotion chip?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Talking the opening scene where they fight the renegade Borg on the outpost. Something all of a sudden causes Data to be angry. I take the hint to be the guy who says every biological organism. As though he's holding something to lure Data.

Answer (score 11):

During the rest of *Descent*, we learn that

> Lore has set himself up as leader of these Borg, who became disconnected from the collective due to Hugh (from the previous episode, *I, Borg*).

He is able to

> give Data the ability to experience some emotions by sending a carrier wave that affects Data's positronic matrix.

As [NKCampbell pointed out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217728/what-exactly-caused-data-to-get-angry-in-descent-before-the-emotion-chip/217730#comment595495_217730), this is [addressed in dialog](http://chakoteya.net/NextGen/253.htm):

> LAFORGE: Data, listen. Lore is controlling you. He's transmitting a carrier wave which is affecting your positronic matrix.

As Troi points out earlier,

> Lore

only seems to allow Data to experience anger and hatred.

> TROI: Data, all I'm sensing from you is anger and hatred. Have you felt any other emotions?
>
>  DATA: There are no other emotions.

We later see him adjusting this while in conversation with Data, and the effects it has.

Comment: So was it a signal sent by Lore to the outpost that managed to somewhat trap Data?

Comment: Yeeees... in the sense that someone is "trapped" by drug addiction; it's an "emotional" trap — literally, in this case — rather than a physical or moral trap. Lore, who *can* feel emotions, somehow broadcasted that ability to Data. (Possibly modified to make it more addictive, since Data *clearly* goes through withdrawl when Lore "dials back"; a problem that doesn't seem to effect Data when he has the real emotion chip, as we see later in e.g. ST8.)